# Top item in a ListView disappears completely even when only partially ouside bounds. How can I fix this?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm learning to use Qt and QML. Right now, I'm trying to use a ListView, and I mostly got it to work, except for this one little visual bug.

When I run the code, at first it looks fine. But if I scroll a little bit, the top item disappears completely. It only appears again when scrolling back enough so that it is entirely within bounds. In the mean time, there's only a ugly blank spot in the list. That happens with every item when it goes over the top bound.

I want the items to be partially drawn. The library is clearly capable of doing this, since this problem doesn't happen in the lower bound, but I simply cannot figure out how to do it.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 360
    height: 520
    visible: true
    title: "Qml.Net"

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 100
        model: ["#111111", "#222222", "#333333", "#444444", "#555555", "#666666"]  


        delegate: Item {
            Rectangle {
                width: 400
                height: 100
                color: modelData

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some pictures of the problem. First image is correct, second image shows the error. Also, notice how the bottom item is correctly drawn.

Correct at first

[image]

Wrong after a little bit of scrolling

[image]

- Qt 5.12

Comment: Right, done. I'm importing QtQuick 2.12 and QtQuick.Controls 2.12, and using Qt 5.12.

Comment: mmm, where you drag the mouse to generate what is shown in the second image. I dragged down and didn't notice the problem, but if I drag up I just notice what you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the "spacing" property that is unnecessary in your case. The solution is to remove that property and rewrite the logic as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 360
    height: 520
    visible: true
    title: "Qml.Net"

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ["#111111", "#222222", "#333333", "#444444", "#555555", "#666666"]  

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 100
            color: modelData
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YES, thank you! The spacing property I had set because in my previous tests if I didn't set it, the tiles would end overlapping each other. I don't know exactly what was the difference between then and your example, but it's certainly something I was doing wrong. Your answer just worked perfectly. Thank you so much for you patience and your help!

Comment: The problem was more due to the wrapping `Item` meaning the delegate had an height of 0. The spacing was a consequence of that to make it somewhat work